# How do I stop my player from leaving the grid in my game?

Tags: c

I have to make a dungeon like game. I've been stuck on the same problem for a while now, my player can leave the grid. Ive tried many ways but i cant figure out how to limit the grid so they cant just leave or tp in to the next column.

```c
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>


struct mapPosition {
    int x, y;
};
struct Player
{
    int gold;
    int maxhealth;  int health;
    int maxstamina; int stamina;
    int maxagility; int agility;
    int maxpotions; int potions;
};


#define SIZE 5

char map[SIZE][SIZE] = { {' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
                         {' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
                         {' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
                         {' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
                         {' ',' ',' ',' ',' '} };

Player player;
int generateHP() {
    return (rand() % 21 + 90); //(110 - 90 + 1)) + 90;    
}
void Health(int value) {
    player.health = 0;
    if (player.health == 0) {
        player.health += generateHP();
    }
    printf("Health = %d/110\n", player.health);
}

void PrintMap()
{
    int value = 0;
    system("cls");
    printf("----- DUNGEON -----\n");
    Health(value);
    printf(" ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("|   |   |   |   |   |\n");
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            printf("| %c ", map[j][i]);
        }
        printf("|\n");
        printf("|___|___|___|___|___|\n");
    }
}
void randomEnemy() {
    int row, col;
    int x = 0;
    while (x < 3)
    {
        row = rand() % SIZE;
        col = rand() % SIZE;
        if (map[row][col] != 'E' && map[row][col] != 'C')
        {
            map[row][col] = 'E';
        }
        else
            x--;

        x++;
    }
}
void randomChest() {
    int row, col;
    int j = 0;
    while (j < 2)
    {
        row = rand() % SIZE;
        col = rand() % SIZE;
        if (map[row][col] != 'E' && map[row][col] != 'C')
        {
            map[row][col] = 'C';
        }
        else
            j--;
        j++;
    }
}

void PlayerMovement(mapPosition& _mapPos) {
    char d;
    printf("Where do you want to go? \n");
    scanf_s("%c", &d);
    map[_mapPos.x][_mapPos.y] = ' ';
    switch (d) {
    case 'W':
        //mapPosition _Pos;
        //_Pos.x = _mapPos.x;
        //_Pos.y = _mapPos.y - 1;
        //if (checkMovement(_Pos) == 0) {
        if (_mapPos.y < 4) {
            _mapPos.y -= 1;
        }
        else{
            
        }
        //else if (checkMovement(_Pos) == 1) {
            //gamestate = 1
        //}
        //else if (checkMovement(_Pos) == 2) {
            ///gamestate = 2
        //}
        //_mapPos.y -= 1;
        break;
    case 'A':
        //mapPosition _Pos;
        //_Pos.x = _mapPos.x - 1;
        //_Pos.y = _mapPos.y;
        //if (_mapPos.x < 5)
        _mapPos.x -= 1;
        //else {

        //}
        break;
    case 'S':
        //mapPosition _Pos;
        //_Pos.x = _mapPos.x;
        //_Pos.y = _mapPos.y + 1;
        _mapPos.y += 1;
        break;
    case 'D':
        //mapPosition _Pos;
        //_Pos.x = _mapPos.x + 1;
        //_Pos.y = _mapPos.y;
        _mapPos.x += 1;
        break;
    }
    map[_mapPos.x][_mapPos.y] = 'P';
}

void Start(mapPosition& _playerPos) {
    randomEnemy();
    randomChest();
    map[_playerPos.x][_playerPos.y] = 'P';
    PrintMap();
}

void Update(mapPosition& _playerPos)
{
    int x = 0;
    while (x < 12)
    {
        PlayerMovement(_playerPos);
        PrintMap();
        x++;
    }
}

void clearMap(mapPosition& _playerPos) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            map[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
}

/*void gameState() {
    if (gameState == 0) {
        //explore
    }
    else if (gameState == 1) {
        //battle
    }
    else if (gameState == 2) {

    }
}*/

int checkMovement(mapPosition& _pos) {
    if (map[_pos.x][_pos.y] == 'E') {
        return 1;
    }
    if (map[_pos.x][_pos.y] == 'C') {
        return 2;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int gameState = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    mapPosition playerPos;
    playerPos.y = 3;
    playerPos.x = 2;
    while (x < 4) {
        Start(playerPos);
        Update(playerPos);
        clearMap(playerPos);
    }
    x++;
}
```

I know the code is janky, but ive only been coding for two months. Any help is appreciated. Its in playerMovement, and I just cant figure out how to do it. Its also not done and has a lot of incomplete things now, but i cant move on without fixing this first.

Comment: This is not valid C code. Did you mean to write C++?

Comment: `case 'W': if (_mapPos.y != 0) { _mapPos.y -= 1; } case 'S': if (_mapPos.y != SIZE - 1) { mapPos.y += 1; }`